# Stored Procedure for multiple inserts with exiting if one fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, entity-attribute-value

I have an EAV table, for each separate attribute I have a new row, something like this:

```
PersonID AtributeName AtributeValue
-----------------------------------
1         Name           John
1         Gender         Male
1         Height         170
```

The problem is that if I want to insert a new Person (with ID 2, name Jack, Male, Height 180) I need 3 more inserts, and there are changes that one ore more could fail. I was thinking of including all this inserts in a stored procedures with parameters (ID, Name, Gender, Height, etc..).

My question is, doing something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InserSubject 
    @ID int, 
    @Name varchar(50), 
    @Gender varchar(50), 
    @Height int
AS
    INSERT INTO Subjects 
    VALUES (1, 'Name', 'John'),
           (1, 'Gender', 'Male'),  
           (1, 'Height', 170);
```

Will fail if one of the inserts fail? Is that kind of implementation for this kind of database/table?

Comment: You could use a TRY CATCH to actually catch the error, if any.

Comment: send a xml object (id,key,value)and then do a insert into select from xml, no need to error handling.

Comment: I think it would be easier for me to implement with Try catch than xml object, only because I haven no clue how. But thank you!

Comment: Every SQL operation is atomic, so is INSERT - it will either fail or pass, there is no way it will partially insert data. In this examples, although you are inserting three rows it's a single INSERT command - either all three rows are inserted or none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InserSubject @ID int, @Name varchar(50), @Gender     varchar(50), @ Height int
    AS
  BEGIN TRY
      INSERT into Subjects Values (1,'Name','John'),(1,'Gender','Male'),  
       (1,'Height',170); 
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
      error_message()
  END CATCH
```

Comment: And one more, what if I don't pass the Height Parameter (because let's say it's optional) will it set it to null?

Comment: yes you can pass null but this is not recommended so instead of null you can use some neutral value like 0 or -1